# using greater than (>) or less than (<) inside {% if statement %} doesnt work

Tags: python, django

I am writing a code for a paginator on my website on my home.html file. When i tried to put a '>' and a '<' the atom text editor read it as an html code. And then the color of the codes after the signs changed as if it they were an html code.

```
{% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'-3' %}
    <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{num}}">
```

[image]

and it made the other page numbers on my paginators disappear.

This is how my paginator should look like:

[image]

ufortunately this happened:

[image]

im missing two sets of numbers before and after my current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your boolean condition will never be met.

```
elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'-3'
```

you're checking if `num` is greater than `page_obj.number-3` and then checking if `num` is also less than `page_obj.number-3`. It can't be both.

Maybe you're looking for:

```
elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3'
```

Comment: ohh right i must have overlooked the negative sign on the second number. thanks!!

Comment: im sorry i forgot to accept it as an answer. by the way, you might be able to help me answer my another question. [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522776/how-to-fetch-an-entire-row-in-a-table-and-display-it-in-a-template-python-djang?noredirect=1#comment97749813_55522776)