# How to fetch an entire row in a table and display it in a template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a ticketing site for a Cinema which my project in school, and I made two models, 1 is `Movie` and 2 `TimeSlot`. `Movie.time_slot` has a `manytomany`relation to `TimeSlot` table.

What I want to happen is, display  the timeslot for the Movie depending on the `Movie.title` and on what `day` it is.

For example, i want the `Time Slots:` row below to display:

Monday: `timeslot1.value`, `timeslot2.value`, `timeslot3.value`, `timeslot4.value`

given that the current day is `Monday` and `timeslots` above were not `empty` or `null`

[image]

Here is my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from PIL import Image

class TimeSlot(models.Model):
    moviename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    day = models.CharField(max_length = 9)
    timeslot1 = models.CharField(max_length = 20,blank = True, null = True)
    timeslot2 = models.CharField(max_length = 20,blank = True, null = True)
    timeslot3 = models.CharField(max_length = 20,blank = True, null = True)
    timeslot4 = models.CharField(max_length = 20,blank = True, null = True)
    timeslot5 = models.CharField(max_length = 20,blank = True, null = True)
    timeslot6 = models.CharField(max_length = 20,blank = True, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.moviename} timeslot for {self.day}'


class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    description = models.TextField()
    release_date = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    time_slot = models.ManyToManyField(TimeSlot, related_name=None)
    available_seats = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default= 300)
    ticket_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(default = 'default.jpg', upload_to = 'media/movie_posters')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title} Info'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Movie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        image = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if image.height > 200 or image.width > 200:
            output_size = (200, 200)
            image.thumbnail(output_size)
            image.save(self.image.path)
```

Here is my `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Movie,TimeSlot


pagetitle = 'Order Tickets Online'

def home(request):
    context = {
        'movielist': Movie.objects.all(),
        'timeslot': TimeSlot.objects.all(),
        'title': pagetitle
    }
    return render(request, 'movies/home.html', context)

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'movies/about.html')
```

And here is my home.html template:

```
{% block content %}

{% for movie in movielist %}

     <article class="media content-section">
       <div class="media-body">
         <div class="article-metadata">
           <a class="mr-2" href="#" style="font-size: 30px"> {{ movie.title}}</a>
           <small class="text-muted" >Showing on: {{ movie.release_date }}</small>
         </div>
         <img src="{{movie.image.url}}" alt="">
         <p class="article-content">
              <strong>Movie Description: </strong>{{ movie.description }} <br>
              <strong>Genre: </strong>{{ movie.genre }} <br>
              <strong>Time Slots: </strong><br>
              <strong>Available Seats: </strong>{{ movie.available_seats }} <br>
              <strong>ticket_price: </strong>{{ movie.ticket_price }} <br>
         </p>
       </div>
     </article>

{% endfor %}


{% endblock %}
```

Anyone who can guide me until this thing works? Newbie in python here, thanks!

Here is what it looks like inside my `django administrator` and under `Movie` app:
[image]

And inside the `Time slots` table here are the data:
[image]

when i click the title:
[image]

Here is what it looks like inside the Movie table:

[image]

Comment: ohhh im sorry i already posted the codes.

Comment: @newbieprogrammer I see your screenshots. Are you sure the existing timeslot is related to the movie instances? If you go into the movie instance, does it show the realted timeslot there?

Comment: @Ralf I updated my question again for you to see what's inside the Movie table, and yes there are timeslots in there. I'm sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [many-to-many example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), you could access to time slots using  `movie_instance.time_slot.all()`.

In your view you could omit the `TimeSlot` queryset:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'movielist': Movie.objects.all(),
        'title': pagetitle
    }
    for m in context['movielist']:    # for debug, remove later
        print(m.time_slot.all())      # for debug, remove later
    return render(request, 'movies/home.html', context)
```

And in your template you can try

```
<strong>Time Slots:</strong>
{% for t in movie.time_slot.all %}
    {{ t.timeslot1 }}
    {{ t.timeslot2 }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

---

Or you could add a method to your model to filter and prepare a string with what you need and then just call that method in your template for each movie instance.

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    def get_monday_time_slots(self):
        return self.time_slot.filter(day='monday')
```

Does that help?

Comment: @RaIf I tried to implement the code above but still, no displayed data on Time Slots: row in my movies panel.

Comment: Are you sure there is data? What do you get with `print(movie.timeslot.all())`?

Comment: @RaIf how should i run the `print(movie.timeslot.all())` should i press ctrl+shift+b while highlighting the line? sorry kinda new to python

Comment: I tried the method and it returned an error `Invalid block tag on line 17: 'get_monday_time_slots.timeslot1', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`. @RaIf

Comment: @newbieprogrammer You can run it in an interpreter session or in your views for now (I edited my answer to include the debug print lines)

Comment: @RaIf when i try to look at the django admininstration there are data in my TimeSlot table `moviename= Friends with Benefits` ,`day=Monday`, `timeslot1= somevalue` etc.

Comment: @newbieprogrammer I changed `timeslot` to `time_slot` in my answer; I think I got them confused because you have both in your models and it seems that I used the wrong one.

Comment: <QuerySet []>
<QuerySet []> I see this in my PowerShell does it mean that the table is empty? @RaIf

Comment: That would indicate that there are no `TimeSlot` instances related to the movies you iterate over (so obviously nothing will be displayed). Are you sure that the data in the database is correct?

Comment: @RaIf I updated my question, and on the bottom i posted the pic inside my `django administrator` for you to see what's inside.